# sql select multiple rows in subselect

Tags: mysql, subquery

First things first, I know this is incorrect currently.  I know this because it doesn't work. So with that said, any assistance in getting me closer to my desired result is appreciated.

I have a query:

```
$query = "SELECT cat.*, 
       prod.title                            AS product, 
       cat1.title                            AS category, 
       (SELECT cat2.* 
        FROM   ic_store_catalog AS cat2 
        WHERE  cat2.parentid = cat.parentid) AS children 
FROM   ic_store_catalog AS cat 
       LEFT JOIN ic_products AS prod 
              ON cat.productid = prod.productid 
       LEFT JOIN ic_product_categories AS cat1 
              ON cat.categoryid = cat1.categoryid 
WHERE  `storeid` = $storeid 
       AND `column` = $column 
       AND `parentid` = 0 
ORDER  BY `the_order` ASC";
```

This errors out giving me: `Operand should contain 1 column(s)` as the problem.  This exists in the sub-select guaranteed.

Now what I need to achieve when I use `print_r` in `PHP` is an `Array` similar in structure to this:

```
[0] => Array
            (
                [catalogID] => 165
                [storeID] => 0
                [categoryID] => 7
                [parentID] => 0
                [productID] => 4
                [title] => 
                [column] => 1
                [the_order] => 1
                [cat_order] => 1
                [category] => Cookies & Brownies
                [children] => Array 
                (
                  [0] => Array (
                      [catalogID] => 166
                      [storeID] => 0
                      [categoryID] => 8
                      [parentID] => 7
                      [productID] => 5
                      [the_order] => 1
                      [cat_order] => 1
                      [category] => Brownies
                  )
                )
            )
```

Any help in getting me closer to this result is appreciated.

Comment: I don't think you can select multiple rows for your `children`

Comment: [this answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4325307/mysql-subquery-to-array) (using jojns and a re-arrangement in code) what you need (cannot be done with a subselect as it must select either one row or one column, but not multiple rows or columns), plus possible duplicate

Answer (score 0):

`(SELECT cat2.* 
        FROM   ic_store_catalog AS cat2 
        WHERE  cat2.parentid = cat.parentid)`

You should replace `cat2.*` by only one column that will represent `children`.

Comment: Problem is, I need everything in the table as listed in my desired array output above -- not a single item.  I literally need everything.

Comment: in a relational database you will see data represented in a row, you can not get a result from MySQL that will look like the php array you posted, you will probably get all the childrens that you for each record.
You will have to use this combination :
`    [catalogID] => 165
                [storeID] => 0
                [categoryID] => 7
                [parentID] => 0
                [productID] => 4` to get all the childrens you need.

Comment: I don't quite understand what you're trying to say in that last statement...  The PHP Array is just a formatted version of the results  from mysql for easier reading..  What I don't quite understand is why with a select i can get multiple rows, but with a select inside of a select i cant..