# mysql merge 2 selects in one

Tags: php, mysql, database

how can i marge these two selects in one to recieve the same result? At the moment i make another select inside while where i select the images, i tryed an inner join select inside first query but it didn't work as expected.
Thank you

```
$select_posts=$dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM tbl_posts
                                INNER JOIN tbl_useri on tbl_posts.id_user=tbl_useri.id_user   ");                        
    $select_posts->execute();
    while ($row=$select_posts->fetch())
    {

    $select_images=$dbh->prepare("SELECT * from tbl_img_post where id_post=:id_post");
    $select_images->bindParam(":id_post",$row['id_post']);
    $select_images->execute();
    while ($rowz=$select_images->fetch())
    {
        $img[]=array(
            "id" => $rowz['id_img_post'],
            "image" => $rowz['img']
        );
    }
        $data[]=array(
                "id" => $row['id_post'],
                "userId" => $row['id_user'],
                "profileImg" => $row['profileImg'],
                "userName" => $row['username'],
                "followed" =>false,
                "postedTime" => "3 hours ago",
                "description" => $row['description'],
                "images" => $img
        );
    }
```

Comment: use a join on `post_id`?

Comment: You could try a left join, where an inner join won't show the post if there are no images, a left join makes the images optional. If it has one, great, if it doesn't the image will just be `NULL`

Do note: if there are 5 images for 1 post, you will also get 5 records returned from the SQL query

Comment: that's why i did not use join because if i have multiple images it returns me same post multiplied, i only want the array of the images

Comment: No way to have a sub array of result but you can look at this => https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4325307/mysql-subquery-to-array